# Why System.out.println "Input" comes out twice?

Tags: java

i'm new to programming and we've got an example from school to understand how Scanner works. My problem is that i do not understand why the message "Input" (System.out.println in the while loop) gets printed twice.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ScannerInput {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Give me a String:");
    String zeichenkette = myScanner.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Give me an Integer:");
    int einInteger = myScanner.nextInt();

    // Output input by user
    System.out.println("String: " + zeichenkette);
    System.out.println("Integer: " + einInteger);
    
    boolean scannerSuccess = false;
    while(!scannerSuccess) {
        System.out.print("Input: ");
        if(myScanner.hasNextInt()) {
            einInteger=myScanner.nextInt();
            myScanner.nextLine();
            scannerSuccess=true;
        } else if(myScanner.hasNextLine()){
            myScanner.nextLine();
            scannerSuccess=false;
        }
    }
    
    
    myScanner.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: What input are you giving it?

Comment: first i give a String, after that an Integer and then another String. When i type in the last String the output is "Input: Input:"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
else if(myScanner.hasNextLine()){
  myScanner.next();
  scannerSuccess=false;
}
```

try this code

Comment: Thanks, thats it. But why does that work?